# Навигация в приложении с BottomNavigationView

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-fragment, bottom-navigation-view

Работаю над приложением с BottomNavigationView. Как сделать так, чтобы после перехода со одной «страницы» на другую и возвращения обратно сохранялось место(определённый фрагмент), откуда я ушел, а не открывалось корневое активити? В основе приложения лежат три активити, объединенные этим самым меню. Всё остальное- фрагменты.

Answer (score 0):

Вы можете сохранить название/номер текущего фрагмента в onSaveInstanceState и при создании активности проверять его, если номер сохранён то открывать этот фрагмент, а если номера нет то открывать корневой фрагмент.